# What is the equivalent pg SQL for this Mysql statement (inner join in UPDATE statement)?

Tags: postgresql

Mysql:

`UPDATE a INNER JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id SET n=1 WHERE b.n > 2`

Postgresql (I know):

`UPDATE a SET n=1 FROM b WHERE b.n > 2 AND a.b_id = b.id`

But what are the equivalent pg statements for:

`UPDATE a OUTER JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id SET n=1 WHERE b.n > 2`

`UPDATE a LEFT JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id SET n=1 WHERE b.n > 2`

More generally, what's the equivalent pg statement if I have several inner join tables (e.g. 3 tables)in Mysql like:

```
UPDATE a 
INNER JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id 
INNER JOIN c on b.c_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN d on c.d_id = d.id 
SET n=1 WHERE d.n > 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can create a subQuery like this (which is very flexible and clear):

```
UPDATE  tblA
SET     colA = subQuery.colA
FROM    (
        SELECT  tblA.id, tblA.colA
        FROM    tblA
                INNER JOIN tblB AS b    ON b.id = tblA.b_id
                INNER JOIN tblC AS c    ON c.id = b.c_id
        WHERE   c.someData > 100
        ) AS subQuery
WHERE   tblA.id = subQuery.id
```

Answer (score 1):

what's the use of the left join if you're filtering it anyway using n > 2 ?

```
Table a:
id | firstname | b_id
1  | elisabeth | 2
2  | sam       | 2
3  | john      | 3

table b:
id | surname
2  | smith
3  | doe

UPDATE a LEFT JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id SET firstname = null WHERE b.id > 2
```

Only john doe will be updated.

As for this one:

```
UPDATE a 
INNER JOIN b on a.b_id = b.id 
INNER JOIN c on b.c_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN d on c.d_id = d.id 
SET n=1 WHERE d.n > 2
```

In postgres :

```
UPDATE a
SET n=1
FROM b, c, d
WHERE a.b_id = b.id
AND b.c_id = c.id
AND c.d_id = d.id
AND d.n > 2
```

Comment: does `FROM b, c, d` do a INNER JOIN on a, b, c, d?

Comment: Yep. You specify the relationship in the where clause.